# How To add image shadow

Tags: css

How to add Image shadow like book I am also add this css but it's not working

```css
img {
  box-shadow: 25px 25px 20px 10px rgb(113 108 108 / 53%);
}
```

```html
<div class="position-relative book_width">
  <div class="overlay mini_book"></div>
  <img src="https://pocketmemories.mojom.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Funeral2.jpg" alt="image">
  <p> Remembering Steve Howell</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your HTML and CSS to verify your issue??

Comment: Take a look at https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `clip-path` with `box-shadow`

```css
img {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 24px rgb(113 108 108 / 53%);
  margin:50px;
  width:200px;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,200% 100%,200% 200%,100% 200%,0 100%);
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://pocketmemories.mojom.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Funeral2.jpg" alt="image">
```

Also like below with some blur:

```css
.box {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.box span {
  filter:blur(2px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.box span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 200% 100%, 200% 200%, 100% 200%, 0 100%);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 24px rgb(113 108 108 / 53%);
  background: rgb(113 108 108 / 53%);
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://pocketmemories.mojom.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Funeral2.jpg" alt="image">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try combination of box-shadow like below:

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
```

**CSS**

```
img {
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #999,
   6px 6px 6px #999,
   8px 8px 8px #999,
   10px 10px 10px #999,
   12px 12px 12px #999,
   14px 14px 14px #999;
}
```

**Note:** Please Adjust values and color as per your requirement :)

Comment: I have just edited it :-) Please check once :-) U may need to adjust a bit. Try few combinations :-)